# HTML Button not calling javascript function as it should

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to program an html button to run a javascript function when clicked. Based on research, I've gathered that a way to do this is as follows:

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked " + (count++) + " times");
};
```

My code creates the button without issue, and the script is coming up on the page source, but for some reason I can't figure out the button will not call the function.

My code is as follows:

```js
function addField {
        document.write("<form method = 'POST' action='equipment_page_admin.php'>");
        document.write("<select name ='1'>");
        document.write("<option value = 'default' selected>---Please Select Equipment---</option>");
        document.write("<option value = '120-130 BBL Vacuum Truck (Blackiron)'>120-130 BBL Vacuum Truck (Blackiron)</option>");
        document.write("<option value = '120-130 BBL Vacuum Truck (Stainless)'>120-130 BBL Vacuum Truck (Stainless)</option>");

  ...
        document.write("<option value = 'Vermiculite (4-Cubic Foot Bags)'>Vermiculite (4-Cubic Foot Bags)</option>");
        document.write("</select>");
        document.write("</form>");
    }


    document.getElementById('button').onclick = addField()
```

```html
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Add more equipment"/>
```

Is there something glaringly obvious I'm missing? I've spent about an hour or two fiddling with the code, trying out different ideas and I feel that I've gotten as close to the answer as I can alone.
Thank you for taking the time to read and help.

Comment: remove the `()` from the function call `addField()`. Also this will write a new page. Since the browser has already parsed the page and you're calling `document.write`.

Comment: Try to learn how to use the browser's error console. It helps a lot to see where you have syntax errors.

Comment: Functions 101: Whenever you have `foo()`, `foo` is executed and its return value will be returned. In your case, since `addField` doesn't return anything, `undefined` is assigned to `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your console if you are using chrome or firebug for an error.  Unless there is more code that you are not showing then you have not declared 'count' anywhere, which will cause the script to fail.

Secondly try this for attaching the click event:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", addField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function declaration

```
function addField {
```

to

```
function addField() {
```

then change the handler

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = addField
```

Answer (score -2):

I would just make a button with html and add a `onclick` event to the button.
More about `onclick` here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp